# ember-rails: undefined method `ember' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f14d10deb88> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting this error with the `ember-rails` gem:

```
ERROR -- : undefined method `ember' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f14d10deb88> (NoMethodError)
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/releases/20130914034514/config/environments/staging.rb:81:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/releases/20130914034514/config/environments/staging.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/deploy/apps/gastos/releases/20130914034514/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've placed the configuration for ember in my environment file (`staging.rb`) like so:

`config.ember.variant = :production`

The only clue that I've gotten from Google so far was [this issue on Github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/98) where the solution was to take out `ember-rails` from the `:assets` group. I'm using Rails 4 already, so I don't even have an `:assets` group in the first place. I should also point out that I've already setup my application to use a `staging` environment, so I'm certain that the problem doesn't have anything to do with its current Rails environment.

Has anyone else solved this problem already? Am I just missing something?

Comment: Currently having the same issue.
Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yup, it turns out I just had to restart the server. If that doesn't work for you, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Crap. Why is that NEVER the first thing I do?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of everyone else who may encounter this error, all I had to do was restart my server and it worked fine afterwards.